# mysqldump alternatives --hex-blob doesn't convert geometry binary columns to hex

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, gis

I'm trying to create a mysqldump in utf8 encoding. The table I'm trying to dump contains geometry columns. Now, when I use the --hex-blob option, the geometry columns don't get converted to hex. Are there any command line alternatives to mysqldump that will be able to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My backups containing geometry columns were all broken and impossible to import due to some conversion errors of those columns to binary.
The `--hex-blob=TRUE` option alone had no effect, but I was able to get healthy dumps with:

```
--extended-insert=FALSE --hex-blob=TRUE
```

There seem to be unresolved bugs with dumps of geometry in MySQL 5.7. If you use geometry, I would suggest testing if you are able to import your backups.